# Undo "discard" local changes after merge in TortoiseHg

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, undo

I just lost a bunch of work because I accidentally clicked "discard" when I tried to merge in remote changes.

Can anyone recommend a way to recover my uncommitted local changes? :'(

Does Mercurial or TortoiseHg store a backup somewhere of the last deleted changes?

Answer (score 4):

Was it through this window?

[image: TortoiseHG]

In which case, I'm afraid, no, there is not.

I believe this window calls the command `hg update -r MY_BRANCH -C`, where the `-C` flag denotes there will be no backups.

As an aside, if it was a different way, you'd want to be looking for .orig files, which would be the format of the backup.